# Dataweave filter condition is not working for less than equal to a string

Tags: filter, mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have this payload and dataweave code, but in the below dataweave Less than is working but not equal to? Can someone please help..how to handle equals also?

**Payload:**

```
[{
        "Id": "1",
        "countryName": "Austria"
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "countryName": "Belgium"
    },
    {
        "Id": "3",
        "countryName": "Canada"
    },
    {
        "Id": "4",
        "countryName": "Dutch"
    }]
```

**Datweave:**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload filter ($.countryName >= "A" and $.countryName <= "D")
```

**output:**

```
[
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "countryName": "Austria"
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "countryName": "Belgium"
  },
  {
    "Id": "3",
    "countryName": "Canada"
  }
]
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQMGl.png)

**Expecting:**

Im expecting the Coutrynames startinng with "D" also in the output

Comment: do you want country names in output that start from A or B or C or D? is it correct?

Comment: Please use [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for code, errors and logs.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that a word that starts with a character will always greater than the character. That condition is wrong. It works if you change the conditions to only filter the first character of the country, using the [index selector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/latest/dw-operators#index-selector):

```js
%dw 2.0 
output application/json
---
payload filter ($.countryName[0] >= "A" and $.countryName[0] <= "D")
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "countryName": "Austria"
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "countryName": "Belgium"
  },
  {
    "Id": "3",
    "countryName": "Canada"
  },
  {
    "Id": "4",
    "countryName": "Dutch"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below DataWeave, which filter all country name start with A to D

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload filter ((item,index) -> item.countryName matches /^([ABCD]).*/)
```

This script filters the input payload to include only those objects whose countryName starts with "A", "B", "C", or "D", as intended. The regular expression ^([ABCD]).* efficiently captures the start of the country names with any of the letters "A" through "D". The use of the character class [ABCD] right after the start of the string (^) ensures that only items meeting the criteria are included in the output.

Below is the screen shot of working code:
[image]